# When I compile my program,it displays "segmentaion fault (or) segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c++, knights-tour

When I compile my program, it displays

> segmentaion fault (or) segmentation fault(core dumped)

My code seems to be working sometimes it gives the number of knight moves on the whole `chessBoard`, when moved on a square randomly chosen from all other paths, possibly a knight can take,but this doesn't seem to work always(just for simplicity,I have taken 5x5 chessboard ), why is this happening,what can i do to fix it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     array<array<int , 5>,5> chessBoard = {};
     array<int , 8> horizontal = {2,1,-1,-2,-2,-1,1,2};
     array<int , 8> vertical = {-1,-2,-2,-1,1,2,2,1};
     array<int, 8> temp ={};
     int count = 0 , t = 0 ,index;
     int cR = 4 , cC = 4 ,square =  1;
     srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0)));

     do
     {
       t = 0;
       for(size_t i = 0;i < 8;i++ )
       {
          cR += vertical[i];
          cC += horizontal[i];

          if(cR > 0 && cR < 8 && cC > 0 && cC < 8 && chessBoard[cR][cC] != -1)
          {
             temp[t] = i;
             t++;

          }
          cR -= vertical[i];
          cC -= horizontal[i];

       }
       if(t > 0)
       {
         index = rand() % t;
         chessBoard[cR][cC] = -1;
         cR += vertical[temp[index]];
         cC += horizontal[temp[index]];
         count++;
       }

       for(size_t j=0;j< t;j++)
         temp[j] = 0;

       square++;
   }while(square <= 25);

    cout<<"count is "<<count;
    return 0;

}
```

The error is Segmentation fault or sometimes it displays Segmentation fault (core dumped),what is wrong?

Comment: You did something wrong with a pointer.  Possibly because you declared your chess board with a size of only 5x5 but you are comparing row and column against `8`.

Comment: You are accessing negative indices: cR += vertical[i]; cC += horizontal[i];

Comment: Just a side note.  Please double check when exactly the segfault occurs, it is very important information. If you compile your program and get a segfault then you have done something seriously wrong to a correct compiler or have a faulty compiler - more wrong that is possible with any kind of code, be it as weird and broken as it may be. But I bet that you do not get the segfault before you actually execute your own program, i.e. the result of compiling and otherwise building your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
array<array<int , 5>,5> chessBoard = {};
```

by

```
array<array<int,8>,8> chessBoard;
```

A segmentation fault is when your program tries to access memory that it's not allowed to.

This does not happen when you compile, but when you run the program.